# Discord api returns 401 unauthorized when trying signin via Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: xml, azure, oauth-2.0, discord, azure-ad-b2c

I'm building up an app that uses Discord OAuth2 to various purposes including user identity, but have encountered an issue that Discord api returns 401 (unauthorized) error when a user tries to signin.

I have a B2C tenant that have the custom policy that contain the `ClaimsProbider` written as:

```
  <ClaimsProvider>
      <!-- The following Domain element allows this profile to be used if the request comes with domain_hint 
           query string parameter, e.g. domain_hint=Discord.com  -->
      <Domain>Discord.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Discord</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Discord-OAUTH">
          <!-- The text in the following DisplayName element is shown to the user on the claims provider 
               selection screen. -->
          <DisplayName>Discord</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">Discord</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">[my key]</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">identify email connections guilds.join rpc rpc.api rpc.notifications.read messages.read</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenResponseFormat">json</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_DiscordSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" DefaultValue="id" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" DefaultValue="first_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" DefaultValue="last_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="email"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="Discord.com" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

The error I collected via Application Insights is:

```
{
    ""Kind"": ""HandlerResult"",
    ""Content"": {
      ""Result"": true,
      ""RecorderRecord"": {
        ""Values"": [
          {
            ""Key"": ""SendErrorTechnicalProfile"",
            ""Value"": ""OAuth2ProtocolProvider""
          },
          {
            ""Key"": ""Exception"",
            ""Value"": {
              ""Kind"": ""Handled"",
              ""HResult"": ""80131500"",
              ""Message"": ""An exception was caught when making a request to URL \""https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me\"" using method \""Get\"". The exception status code was \""ProtocolError\"" with the following message: {scrubbed}."",
              ""Data"": {},
              ""Exception"": {
                ""Kind"": ""Handled"",
                ""HResult"": ""80131509"",
                ""Message"": ""The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."",
                ""Data"": {}
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269517/discord-add-guild-member-401-error-despite-apparently-valid-access-token)'s a solution to avoid getting 401 when requesting a claim to the api, but I'm not sure how it works in this situation with a custom policy on B2C tenant.

Could anyone please provide a suggestion to this issue?

Comment: Do you have a full working sample of Discord custom policies? It would be useful to see a working completed gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Discord API requires the access token to be sent in the `Authorization` HTTP header.

By default, Azure AD B2C sends the access token in the query string, so you must add the **BearerTokenTransmissionMethod** metadata item to the technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Discord-OAUTH">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
  </Metadata>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you so much for your suggestion. Did you get this solution because you're already familiar with Discord or just explored into the documentation? I have been seeking an idea for a whole day but it's fruitless. Would you mind giving me a good practice or guide on the web to explore such a kind of configurations depending on each system?