# Adding user to discord guild generates unuathorized error

Tags: php, discord

Edit: I'm wondering if I am adding my bot wrong?  The bot is on the same application as the user's OAuth 2.  The bot was added with:
https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={my id}&scope=bot&permissions=267906503

I have an OAuth2 connection with Discord using https://github.com/wohali/oauth2-discord-new  This returns the discord user and my access token.  It has scopes for:

```
   $authUrl = $this->provider->getAuthorizationUrl([
      'scope' => [
        'identify',
        'email',
        'guilds.join']
      ]);
```

Using the same discord application, I have a bot set up.  The bot is a member of the guild, and the bot is responsive to chat pings (meaning, it's working).  The bot has the create instant invite permission.

Right after I get the discord user back, and have just generated the access token, I am trying to add that user to my guild.

I have tried this with the restcord library and then directly with guzzle.

```
    $guzzle = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6']);

    $guildId = $this->discordApplication->guildId();
    $request = new Request('PUT', 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/'.$guildId.'/members/'.$user->discordId(), [
      'Authorization' => 'Bot '.$this->discordApplication->accessToken()->__toString(),
      "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    ] );
    var_dump($request);
    $response = $guzzle->send($request);
    var_dump($response);
```

It is generating a 401 error.  I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962204/discord-oauth2-join-guild) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269517/discord-add-guild-member-401-error-despite-apparently-valid-access-token) to make sure my content type was right, that my authorization header was right, my OAuth scope was right, and my bot permissions were right.

The output is:

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)#82 (7) {
  ["method":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  string(3) "PUT"
  ["requestTarget":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  NULL
  ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri)#83 (7) {
    ["scheme":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(5) "https"
    ["userInfo":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["host":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(14) "discordapp.com"
    ["port":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    NULL
    ["path":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(60) "/api/v6/guilds/{right guild id}/members/{the right user id}"
    ["query":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fragment":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Host"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "discordapp.com"
    }
    ["Authorization"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(34) "Bot {my oauth2 bearer access token}"
    }
    ["Content-Type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "application/json"
    }
  }
  ["headerNames":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  array(3) {
    ["authorization"]=>
    string(13) "Authorization"
    ["content-type"]=>
    string(12) "Content-Type"
    ["host"]=>
    string(4) "Host"
  }
  ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  string(3) "1.1"
  ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  NULL
}
Client error: `PUT https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/{guildid}/members/{userid}` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response:
{"code": 0, "message": "401: Unauthorized"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

```
   $request = new Request(
      'PUT', 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/'.$guildId.'/members/'.$user->discordId(),
      [
        'Authorization' => 'Bot '.$this->botToken,
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
      ],
      '{"access_token" : "'. $this->discordApplication->accessToken()->__toString().'"}'
      );
```