# guild.members with User Token not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, token

I'm making a Discord bot and want to use guild.members to get a list of all the members. I encountered a problem which is that guild.members is only returning the bot itself, and not any member in the server.

What I tried was to enable intents in my code and in the Discord developers portal but it still did not make a change.

My issue it that I'm trying to use guild.members using a  user token but it isn't working.

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from discord.flags import Intents

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)
guild = bot.get_guild(790189441695350807)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await uwu()

async def uwu():
    for i in guild.members:
        print(i)
bot.run(LmaoWhyYouTrynaStealMyToken>:c)
```

Comment: `guild` is undefined?

Comment: Also, `LmaoWhyYouTrynaStealMyToken>:c` is invalid syntax

Comment: @ForceBru its just to hide the api token

Comment: guild is defined i forgot to add it to the code on stack overflow

Comment: did you try these answers here ?  **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269517/discord-add-guild-member-401-error-despite-apparently-valid-access-token**

Comment: @Aladin no i didnt as i am writing it in python