# Procedure for logging into Discord OAuth using PKCE

Tags: c#, oauth, discord.net

I'm attempting to add Discord OAuth to a mobile app using [PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce). I'm able to successfully authenticate with DiscordAPI, and I receive a `code` back from the server.

However, when I try to call the `https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token` endpoint I continually get a `Bad Request` result.

I've tried a few approaches to attaining my token, but all have failed.

**Attempt (1) using HttpClient:**

```
var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Constants.ClientId));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Constants.Secret));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code_verifier", codeVerifier)); // method param
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", authCode)); // method param
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", Constants.Redirect));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "identify email connections"));

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token") 
{ 
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) 
};
var authTokenResponse = await this.Client.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(false);
// results in BadRequest
```

I've also tried using a `StringContent` object like this:

```
var stringContent = new StringContent($"grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={Constants.ClientId}&client_secret={Constants.Secret}&code_verifier={codeVerifier}&code={authCode}&redirect_uri={Constants.Redirect}&scopes=identify%20email%20connections", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Both of these result in `Bad Request`

**Attempt (2) using RestSharp**

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient($"{this.Client.BaseAddress}/oauth2/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $"grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={Constants.ClientId}&client_secret={Constants.Secret}&code_verifier={code}&code={authCode}&redirect_uri={Constants.Redirect}&scopes=identify%20email%20connections", ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

I've carefully double-checked all of my values and made sure my Client Id and Secret are correct. I've tried sending the request with and without the `code_verifier`. Without the `code_verifier` I get `Unauthorized`.

## Question

How should I modify my HttpClient request to successfully attain my auth token?

**More info:**

To comply with PKCE, I need a `code_verifier`. This is how I'm generating the code. (Note, I am **not** trying to use this as an auth code.)

```
Random rng = new Random();
byte[] code = new byte[32];
rng.NextBytes(code);

CodeVerifier = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(rng.ToString());
```

Then I use a hashing algorithm borrowed from [c-sharpcorner.com](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/compute-sha256-hash-in-c-sharp/), which looks like this:

```
using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
{
    // ComputeHash - returns byte array  
    var bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));

    // Convert byte array to a string   
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

I pass the result as my `code_challenge` while attaining my auth code.

Here's is where I learned that PKCE was required.

https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/450

PKCE discussion continues here:

https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/1296

**Update:**

Alright, so based [iwokal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282739/1664443) answer, I re-read the posts linked above, so PKCE is only "required" if you are using a `Custom Scheme Redirect`, if you are just using an `http` redirect just leave the `code_verifier` out and you are good to go.

That said, this **PKCE workflow is undocumented**. Since I spent 500 points, I'll award the points to whoever is able to resolve the PKCE OAuth workflow.

## You can cook up a solution from scratch and I'll test it.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Code first is used to protected the client,  The Client requests a code from the provider, the client give the code to your sever, and your server request the Token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your request to the wrong url.  The Code flow is created to prevent leaking the client token.  The flow is as the following

1. The Client requests a code from the discord server
2. The Client sends that code to your server
3. Your server passes the code to the discord server with it's secrets
4. Discord Server responds back to the configured redirect_uri, to obtain the token.

Note: there are 2 redirect uri, 1, which resolves the code and another which resolves the token.

You're trying to make your request directly to the token endpoint. You need to make a request to the Authorize endpoint. To obtain a token

> https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=157730590492196864&scope=identify%20guilds.join&state=15773059ghq9183habn&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fnicememe.website&prompt=consent

```
var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var codeParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
codeParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Constants.ClientId));
codeParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", Constants.Redirect));
codeParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "identify email connections"));
codeParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_type", "code"));
codeParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("state", state))

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
"https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize") 
{ 
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) 
};
var authTokenResponse = await this.Client.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Discord will then respond your `redirect_uri` with the code and the state

> https://mywebsite.com/?code=NhhvTDYsFcdgNLnnLijcl7Ku7bEEeee&state=15773059ghq9183habn

Note: The original request to the Authorize doesn't contain your client secret, the client secret is only used from your server. This way only the server can request AuthTokens
Note: most places that support oauth require you to setup you're redirect url with the server.
Note: the state will also be returned with the code verify the state you sent is the one returned.

Take the code the returned to you (NhhvTDYsFcdgNLnnLijcl7Ku7bEEeee) and use the to request a token using your original example, with the proper code:

```
var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Constants.ClientId));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Constants.Secret));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code_verifier", codeVerifier)); // method param
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", authCode)); // method param
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", Constants.Redirect));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "identify email connections"));

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
"https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token") 
{ 
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) 
};
var authTokenResponse = await this.Client.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Note make sure when you make a request to the Token endpoint your using

> 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

If your still having trouble with the flow, Use Postman it has built in OAuth support and obtain the token, watch what they send with fiddler, and emulate it.

Comment: Thanks johnny number 5, I'll look through this post this evening.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Okay let me know if you have any confusion. When I implemented OAuth was in the same position you were, but once I understood why things were done everything clicked, that's why I explained the flow first.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after some research i might have idea what is going on. Are you trying to get token based by authorisation code created by you?

I believe that the correct way is to sent https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize request which will redirect to provided url with querystring containing proper auth code.

You should use this code in the step of getting token.

I don't know if this changes anything but I believe that there is no such parameter as "scopes" according to documentation it should be "scope".

Comment: Thanks for chiming in iwokal, I tried using `"scope"` rather than `"scopes"` and I'm still seeing 400 "Bad Request".

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I am not sure if I understand correctly, but seeing the part with code verifier and hashing algorithm leads me to assume that you are creating auth code by yourself instead of using code returned from Discord Api. To help you in the process i found these two topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260556/discord-oauth-code-usage and https://www.yogihosting.com/discord-api-asp-net/

Comment: No, I've wired up OAuth many times I do understand the workflow. I am not trying to create my own auth code. This is the first time I've had to use PKCE (linked in OP) which is a way for the server to tell that its speaking to the same client for each request.

I've read both of those links in my debugging, they are outdated. I'll find the article that describes that PKCE is necessary and link it to my OP.

Comment: Links added to OP where PKCE is described as needed for OAuth

Comment: You may have led me on the right path here, it says PKCE is needed for "Custom Scheme Redirect", maybe if I switch to a standard http:// redirect, this will work.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for putting me on the right track.